# unable to trigger beforeShowDay using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, datepicker

I am new to knockoutJS where I am trying to bind a datepicker using custom binding. Below is my viewmodel JS file.

```
/*Date picker value binder for knockout*/
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

    var options = {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
       beforeShowDay: function (date) {

            alert('looking for an alert');
            return [false, '', 'available'];
        },
        showOn: "both"
    };

    $(element).datepicker(options);

    $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ev.date);

    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
}
};



/*View model*/
 function ViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.dateFromClient = ko.observable('12/12/2010')
                        .extend({ required: true });
 }


$(document).ready(function () {

//model binding with validation
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

And below is my view.

```
 <div>

        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="datepicker" data-bind="datepicker: dateFromClient" />

  </div>
```

What I am looking for is disabling few dates to be clicked on the calender. And this is the reason why I started with returning false (hoping every date on the picker to be disabled. ) But I am not seeing any date being disabled.

Can someone guide me the correct path to do so?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? As far as I remember beforeShowDay must return an array with a true/false value, css class and optional tooltip i.e. [false,"","Not available"]. In your case you are returning just a boolean value.

Comment: @Jerry. Thanks Jerry for responding. I have updated the question for beforeShowDay method and ran the application again. But I am not seeing the days disabled. I am not seeing any errors in the console also. Can you help me now?

Comment: you looking for something like this now i can see every date in picker disabled . check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X82aC/1243/

Comment: Hmm..
@Supercool, your fiddle is the one that I am looking for, But
 Not sure whats happening with my project. Now I am even unable to see the calender :( I have just updated the jqueryUI, jquery versions and appropriately referred them in my cshtml file.

Comment: ooh i see . all i can suggest now is just maintain the order like jquery,jquery ui , ko like that . cheers let us know for futher issue on this .

Comment: Yes its in the same order :(

Comment: hmm Not sure how... But its working now.. Didnt do any changes though

Comment: @supercool, can you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: done :)  Hope this answer helps others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

**view:**

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="datepicker:$data.dateFromClient" />
```

**viewModel:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = {
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                alert('looking for an alert');
                return [false, '', 'available'];
            },
            showOn: "both"
        };

        $(element).datepicker(options);

        $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable(ev.date);

        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");
        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);   
        }
    }
};


/*View model*/
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.dateFromClient = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X82aC/1243/)**